# API - Dataframe - getting updated value in the same 1st row instead of new row each time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, api, xlwings

Problem: (I am getting updated value in the same 1st row instead of new row each time.)

Details: I am trying to get live data from API, I am trying from several days but no code is giving proper dataframe results.

I am having around 100-150 stocks list to be read from .xlsx file and trying to get live data in dataframe and then write it in .xlsx file (1 stock in 1 sheet, 2nd stock in 2nd sheet in below format:

```
Date         Time    Symbol ltp      ltq    Volume
2021-10-01  11:00:00    A   103.45  50430   110350470
2021-10-01  11:00:01    A   104.29  99500   110400900
2021-10-01  11:00:02    A   105.14  70570   110500400
2021-10-01  11:00:03    A   105.99  90640   110570970
2021-10-01  11:00:04    A   106.84  65710   110661610
2021-10-01  11:00:05    A   107.69  98780   110727320
2021-10-01  11:00:06    A   108.54  84850   110826100
2021-10-01  11:00:07    A   109.39  77920   110910950
2021-10-01  11:00:08    A   110.24  61990   110988870
2021-10-01  11:00:09    A   111.09  53060   111050860
2021-10-01  11:00:10    A   111.94  74130   111103920
```

and in 1 Main sheet Dashboard with hyperlink to check each stock:
e.g.

```
Sr  StockSheet Name ltp high    open    low previous close  Today's volume
1   A   001_A                        
2   B   002_B                        
3   C   003_C                        
4   D   004_D                        
5   E   005_E                        
6   F   006_F                        
7   G   007_G                        
8   H   008_H                        
9   I   009_I                        
10  J   010_J
```

after credential and access token of API below is the main code:

```
socket_opened = False

def event_handler_quote_update(tick):

    tick_symbol = tick['instrument'].symbol
    tick_ltp = tick['ltp']
    tick_volume = tick['volume']
    tick_ltq = tick['ltq']
    tick_ltt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tick['ltt'])
    tick_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tick['exchange_time_stamp'])

    d = {'symbol': [tick_symbol], 'ltp': [tick_ltp], 'ltq': [tick_ltq], 'volume': [tick_volume], 'ltt': [tick_ltt], 'timestamp': [tick_timestamp]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    xw.Book('test1.xlsx').sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1').value = df
    print(df)
    

def open_callback():
    global socket_opened
    socket_opened = True


alice.start_websocket(event_handler_quote_update, open_callback, run_in_background=True)

call = ()

for symbol in fno_list:
    callable(alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', symbol))

while socket_opened == False:
    pass
    alice.subscribe(alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', 'RELIANCE'), LiveFeedType.MARKET_DATA)
```

Code Ended.

Help: As I am new and learning python I'm looking forward for any improvement/suggestions/better way to do this.

Comment: Can anybody please help to solve this ?